# How to efficiently select records matching substring in another table using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of several million strings that I want to match against a table of about twenty thousand strings like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT record.* FROM `record`
JOIN `fragment` ON record.name
  LIKE CONCAT('%', fragment.name, '%')
```

Unfortunately this is taking an awful long time.

Considering that the `fragment` table is only 20k records, can I load it into a JavaScript array using a UDF and match it that way? I'm trying to figure out how to this right now but perhaps there's already some magic I could do here to make this faster. I tried a `CROSS JOIN` and got resource exceeded fairly quickly. I've also tried using `EXISTS` but I can't reference the `record.name` inside that subquery's `WHERE` without getting an error.

## Example using Public Data

This seems to reflect about the same *amount* of data ...

```
#standardSQL
WITH record AS (
  SELECT LOWER(text) AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), fragment AS (
  SELECT LOWER(name) AS name, COUNT(*)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
  GROUP BY name
)
SELECT record.* FROM `record`
JOIN `fragment` ON record.name
  LIKE CONCAT('%', fragment.name, '%')
```

Comment: can you think of any public data that you can use as an example?

Comment: good example - see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH record AS (
  SELECT LOWER(text) AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), fragment AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(name) AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
), temp_record AS (
  SELECT record, TO_JSON_STRING(record) id, name, item 
  FROM record, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(name, r'\w+')) item 
), temp_fragment AS (
  SELECT name, item FROM fragment, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(name, r'\w+')) item
)
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(record) FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(record) record, id, r.name name, f.name fragment_name
  FROM temp_record r
  JOIN temp_fragment f
  USING(item)
  GROUP BY id, name, fragment_name
) 
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', fragment_name, '%')
GROUP BY id
```

above was completed in 375 seconds, while original query is still running at 2740 seconds and keep running, so I will not even wait for it to complete

Comment: shouldn't he remove the 1st % to use the database index since '%'fragment_name'%' will do a full table scan every time ?

Comment: he is using BigQuery - no index relevant here. Also `name LIKE CONCAT('%', fragment_name, '%')` mean match all name where value of fragment_name is anywhere inside value of name

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail's answer appears to be faster - but lets have one that doesn't need to `SPLIT` nor separate the text into words.

First, compute a regular expression with all the words to be searched:

```
#standardSQL
WITH record AS (
  SELECT text AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), fragment AS (
  SELECT name AS name, COUNT(*)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
  GROUP BY name
)
SELECT FORMAT('(%s)',STRING_AGG(name,'|'))
FROM fragment
```

Now you can take that resulting string, and use it in a `REGEX` ignoring case:

```
#standardSQL
WITH record AS (
  SELECT text AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), largestring AS (
   SELECT '(?i)(mary|margaret|helen|more_names|more_names|more_names|josniel|khaiden|sergi)'
)

SELECT record.* FROM `record`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(record.name, (SELECT * FROM largestring))
```

(~510 seconds)

Comment: I noticed the `LIMIT 10` in there which would reduce the number of fragments. I'm wondering what the limit on a string aggregation is in BigQuey.

Comment: Oops. Just removed the `LIMIT 10`. It worked for me (~510 seconds)

.

Comment: just to double-check  - have you rerun string for `largestring` as it still has 10 items?

Comment: Yes. It would take way less than ~510 seconds if I only had 10 names.

Answer (score 0):

As eluded to in my question, I worked on a version using a JavaScript UDF which solves this albeit in a slower way than the answer I accepted. For completeness, I'm posting it here because perhaps someone (like myself in the future) may find it useful.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CONTAINS_ANY(str STRING, fragments ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  for (var i in fragments) {
    if (str.indexOf(fragments[i]) >= 0) {
      return fragments[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
""";

WITH record AS (
  SELECT text AS name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
  WHERE text IS NOT NULL
), fragment AS (
  SELECT name AS name, COUNT(*)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
  WHERE name IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY name
), fragment_array AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(name) AS names, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM fragment
  GROUP BY LENGTH(name)
), records_with_fragments AS (
  SELECT record.name,
    CONTAINS_ANY(record.name, fragment_array.names)
      AS fragment_name
  FROM record INNER JOIN fragment_array
    ON CONTAINS_ANY(name, fragment_array.names) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rownum) FROM (
  SELECT record.name,
         records_with_fragments.fragment_name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY record.name) AS rownum
  FROM record
  INNER JOIN records_with_fragments
     ON records_with_fragments.name = record.name
    AND records_with_fragments.fragment_name IS NOT NULL
) WHERE rownum = 1
```

The idea is that the list of fragments is relatively small enough that it can be processed in an array, similar to Felipe's answer using regular expressions. The first thing I do is create a `fragment_array` table which is grouped by the fragment lengths ... a cheap way of preventing an over-sized array *which* I found can cause UDF timeouts.

Next I create a table called `records_with_fragments` that joins those arrays to the original records, finding only those which contain a matching fragment using the JavaScript UDF `CONTAINS_ANY()`. This will result in a table containing some duplicates since one record may match multiple fragments.

The final `SELECT` then pulls in the original `record` table, joins to `records_with_fragments` to determine which fragment matched, and also uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to prevent duplicates, e.g. only showing the first row of each record as uniquely identified by its `name`.

Now, the reason I do the join in the final query is because in my actual data there are more fields I want besides just the string being matched. Earlier on in my actual data I create a table of `DISTINCT` strings which then later need to be re-joined.

*Voila!* Not the most elegant but it gets the job done.